# How to install ruby-2.1.6 binaries for rvm on centos6

Tags: ruby, build, centos, rubygems, rvm

I need ruby-2.1.6 binaries for rvm on (centos6)

While searching I found this : https://rvm.io/binaries/centos/6/x86_64/

but this doesn't have ruby-2.1.6 while it has 2.1.5

But for osx-10.10, the rvm has ruby-2.1.6,

https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.10/x86_64/

so can I use osx ruby gems for centos6?

or

Is there a way to build ruby-2.1.6 binaries from source for centos6?

Thanks guys

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Comment: but what didn't you understand ? @sawa

Comment: @SampathKanth have you installed RVM ?

Comment: @RameshKumarThiyagarajan : I have the knowledge of installing ruby with rvm and also manage with different versions of ruby using rvm.
For example :
using rvm it installs default in **/usr/local/rvm** directory, can I specify the directory to install ?

or 

Can I copy or move the gems which installed in that default directory to any other directory ? If I can move, which folders do I need to move.
While using rvm, it has installed all its folder

 **tmp
 src
 gems
wrappers
 user
rubies
 log
environments
config**
I definitely know rubies is the folder, any other folders to move or copy?
Thanks